# ngx-mat-select-search multiple field toggle all form control not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-select

i'm using ngx mat select search toggle all option on a multiple mat select field
single selection works fine, but toggle all checkbox is not selecting the rest of checkbox, and formcontrol bankMultiCtrl is not updating the selected list

it seems form control is not associated to mat select.
Please help i'm ts begginer

Here is my html

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Modificacion de Padrones</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div>
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/user.png" width="60" height="60" class="img-radius"
                alt="User-Profile-Image">
        </div>        
        <div>        
            <h4 class="f-w-600">{{ prestadorData.numero||('(sin número)') }} - {{prestadorData.nombre}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align m-5">
      <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            Anadir especialidad/padrón
          </mat-panel-title>
          <mat-panel-description>
            Seleccione una especialidad y un padron
            <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
          </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        
        <form *ngIf="!loading" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="enviarEspecialidad()">
          <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlexFill fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap.lg="10px">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex>           
              <mat-select [formControl]="dataCtrl" ngDefaultControl placeholder="Especialidad" #singleSelect formControlName = "especialidad">
                <mat-option>
                  <ngx-mat-select-search placeholderLabel="Seleccione una especialidad." 
                  noEntriesFoundLabel="Sin coincidencias."
                    [formControl]="dataFilterCtrl"
                  ></ngx-mat-select-search>
                </mat-option>
          
                <mat-option *ngFor="let x of filteredData | async" [value]="x.id">
                  {{x.nombre}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          
            
          <div fxFlex>
            <p>
              <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                <mat-select [formControl]="bankMultiCtrl" ngDefaultControl placeholder="Padrones" [multiple]="true" #multiSelect formControlName = "padrones">
                  <mat-option>
                    <ngx-mat-select-search 
                    [showToggleAllCheckbox]="true"                                        
                    (toggleAll)="toggleSelectAll($event)"
                    [formControl]="bankMultiFilterCtrl"
                    placeholderLabel="Seleccione uno o más padrones." 
                    noEntriesFoundLabel="Sin coincidencias.">
                  </ngx-mat-select-search>
                  </mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let padron of filteredBanksMulti | async" [value]="padron">
                    {{padron.nombre}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            

            <p>
              Selected Banks:
            </p>
            <ul *ngFor="let bank of bankMultiCtrl?.value">
              <li>{{bank.nombre}}</li>
            </ul>
           
          </div>
          

          <div fxFlex>
            <button type="submit"  [disabled]="form.invalid"   mat-raised-button color="primary">Añadir</button>            
          </div>          
      </div>
    </form>
    
      </mat-expansion-panel>      
    </mat-accordion>
    
    <div fxLayout="row " fxFlexFill fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div fxFlex class="mat-title">Especialidad/Padrón</div>
      <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end center"> <button  (click)="mostrarDialogo('¿ Realmente desea quitar al prestador de todos los padrones ?')" mat-button color="warn">Quitar de todos los padrones</button> </div>  
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let zn of prestadorData.padrones_especialidad | group_padron  ">
      
      <mat-chip color="primary" selected> {{zn[0].especialidad.nombre}}
        <button matChipRemove  (click)="mostrarDialogo()">
          <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
        </button>   
      </mat-chip> 
        
        <mat-list class="m-b-10">
          <mat-chip class="m-3" *ngFor="let pd of zn"> {{pd.padron.nombre}}
            <button matChipRemove (click)="mostrarDialogo()">
              <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
            </button>   
          </mat-chip>           
        </mat-list>  
        <mat-divider class="m-5"></mat-divider>
    </div>
   
</mat-dialog-content>    
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Volver</button>

</div>
```

and heres is my ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, EventEmitter, Inject, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, UntypedFormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule, MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/internal/ReplaySubject';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from 'src/app/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { Prestador } from 'src/app/interfaces/prestador';
import { take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';
import { PrestadoresService } from 'src/app/services/prestadores.service';

export interface Especialidad {
  id: number;
  nombre: string;
}

export interface Padrones {
  id: number;
  nombre: string;  
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-padrones',
  templateUrl: './padrones.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./padrones.component.css']
})
export class PadronesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {  

  form: FormGroup;  
    loading = false;    

  dataModel: Especialidad[] = []; //DataModels
  dataCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  dataFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filteredData: ReplaySubject<Especialidad[]> = new ReplaySubject<Especialidad[]>(1);
  @ViewChild('singleSelect', { static: true }) singleSelect!: MatSelect;

  public padrones: Padrones[] = [];
    /** control for the selected bank for multi-selection */
  public bankMultiCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  /** control for the MatSelect filter keyword multi-selection */
  public bankMultiFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  /** list of banks filtered by search keyword */
  public filteredBanksMulti: ReplaySubject<Padrones[]> = new ReplaySubject<Padrones[]>(1);
  @ViewChild('multiSelect') multiSelect!: MatSelect;


  @Input() toggleAllCheckboxChecked = false; 

  @Input() toggleAllCheckboxIndeterminate = false; 
  /** Subject that emits when the component has been destroyed. */
  protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();


  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PadronesComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public prestadorData: Prestador,
    public dialogo: MatDialog,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private _prestadorService: PrestadoresService,
    private fb:FormBuilder,
    
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        especialidad: ['',Validators.required] ,
        padrones: ['',Validators.required]
    });

   }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.load();

    this.loadPadrones();
    // this.dataModel is empty array  as response is asynchronous
    console.log('DataModel after load()', this.dataModel.slice());
    //this.filteredData.next(this.dataModel.slice());

    this.testSubscribeFilteredData();
    this.testSubscribeFilteredMultiData();

    this.dataFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterData();
      });

    this.bankMultiFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy)) 
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterDataMulti();
      });
      
      
    

      
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.setInitialValue();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }

  mostrarDialogo(message?: string): void {
    this.dialogo
      .open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
        data: message ? message : `¿Confirma la acción?`
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((confirmado: Boolean) => {
        if (confirmado) {
          this.snack("Acción confirmada");
          
        } else {
          this.snack("Acción cancelada");
          
        }
      });
  }

  comboChange(event:any) {
    console.log(event);
    if(!event) {      
      this.valueSelected = this.bankMultiCtrl.value && this.bankMultiCtrl.value.toString();
      console.log(this.valueSelected);
    }
    
  }

  enviarEspecialidad(message?: string): void {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.dialogo
      .open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
        data: message ? message : `¿Confirma la acción?`
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((confirmado: Boolean) => {
        if (confirmado) {
          this.snack("Acción confirmada");
          
        } else {
          this.snack("Acción cancelada");
          
        }
      });
  }

  snack(message: string) {
    this._snackBar.open(message, 'OK', {
        duration: 5000,
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      verticalPosition: 'bottom',
    });
  }

  /**
   * Sets the initial value after the filteredBanks are loaded initially
   */
   protected setInitialValue() {
    

      this.filteredBanksMulti
      .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        // setting the compareWith property to a comparison function
        // triggers initializing the selection according to the initial value of
        // the form control (i.e. _initializeSelection())
        // this needs to be done after the filteredBanks are loaded initially
        // and after the mat-option elements are available
        this.multiSelect.compareWith = (a: Padrones, b: Padrones) => a && b && a.id === b.id;
      });
  }

  toggleSelectAll(selectAllValue: boolean) {
    
    this.filteredBanksMulti.pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(val => {
        console.log('toggle All', val)    ;    
        if (selectAllValue) {
          this.bankMultiCtrl.patchValue(val);
        } else {
          this.bankMultiCtrl.patchValue([]);
        }
      });
  }

  filterData() {
    if (!this.dataModel) {
      return;
    }
    let search = this.dataFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredData.next(this.dataModel.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    this.filteredData.next(
      this.dataModel.filter(
        (x: any) => x.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
      )
    );
  }

  filterDataMulti() {
    if (!this.padrones) {
      return;
    }
    let search = this.bankMultiFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredBanksMulti.next(this.padrones.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    this.filteredBanksMulti.next(
      this.padrones.filter(
        (x: any) => x.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
      )
    );
  }

  load() {
    return this._prestadorService.getEspecialidades().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataModel = res;

      console.log('DataModel within subscribe', this.dataModel);
      this.filteredData.next(this.dataModel.slice());
      
    });
  }

  loadPadrones() {
    return this._prestadorService.getPadrones().subscribe(res => {
      this.padrones = res;

      this.allBanksSize = this.padrones?.length;

      console.log('DataModel within subscribe', this.dataModel);
      this.filteredBanksMulti.next(this.padrones.slice());

      
    });
  }

  testSubscribeFilteredData() {
    this.filteredData.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Subscribed filteredData', data);
    });
  }

  testSubscribeFilteredMultiData() {
    this.filteredBanksMulti.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Subscribed filteredData', data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check when you click the toggle all what value you are getting in selectAllValue?   toggleSelectAll(selectAllValue: boolean)

Comment: selectAll get true or false when check or uncheck first checkbox .

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-13-starter-x1xj4z-de63pc?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: The the implementation from the stackblitz provided by @cfprabhu works!